# libpng warning iccp known incorrect srgb profile error in blender

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

[image: error comes in my blender file]

what is the reason,image render comes in black and white?

help me to find the solution, thanks

Comment: Check if you are previewing the right channel in the render window. You might look at the alpha channel currently

Comment: How does the title of the post relate to the rest of the question. In what circumstances are you getting such message. Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: @cegaton in render image ,objects are rendered by white and black